# When to know if I can use double colon with lambda?

Tags: java, lambda

Of the following lines, why is the first and last allowed ?

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();

l.stream().forEach(System.out::println);//compiles
l.stream().forEach(System.out.println(String::compareTo));//doesnt compile
l.stream().forEach(String::compareTo);// doesnt compile 

String comparedWith = "";

l.stream().forEach(comparedWith::compareTo);//compiles why ?
```

## edit

If [compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))  takes **one** argument, shouldn't it work also ?

If according to docs:

> Represents an operation that accepts a single input argument and
>   returns no   result. Unlike most other functional interfaces, {@code
>   Consumer} is expected   to operate via side-effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> l.stream().forEach(System.out::println);//compiles

This calls the `println` method of `System.out` for each item. Here `System.out::println` is the same as `(String x) -> System.out.println(x)`.

> l.stream().forEach(System.out.println(String::compareTo));//doesnt compile

You know how function calls work, right? This first calls `(System.out.println(String::compareTo)`, then calls `l.stream().forEach(result of that println call)`. Except `println` returns `void` so it has no result.

> l.stream().forEach(String::compareTo);// doesnt compile

Here `String::compareTo` is the same as `(String x, String y) -> x.compareTo(y)` which takes two arguments. But `forEach` needs a lambda that takes one argument.

String comparedWith = "";

> l.stream().forEach(comparedWith::compareTo);//compiles why ?

Here `comparedWith::compareTo` is the same as `(String x) -> comparedWith.compareTo(x)`. This takes one argument so it's valid.

Comment: why does the third example be the same as `(String x, String y) -> x.compareTo(y)`, can you please elaborate with this ?

Comment: @estebanrincon because `String`'s method `compareTo` is not static and therefore needs a String to be called on; it also takes another String as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

forEach will take each element of the collection and pass it to your function. So, your function has to take only one argument.

In your case, println takes one argument, thus it fits into the operation forEach accepts. When you take the instance of the String (comparedWith) and call compareTo, it takes one argument and compares the current string (empty string in your case) with your argument. There is no static methods in String that are called compareTo, so String::compareTo doesn't work.

Comment: `compareTo` also takes one argument, so why doesn't it work ?

Comment: `comapareTo` actually takes two arguments, the `this` reference to the invoking instance, and the declared parameter: `x.compareTo(y)`. As stated above, the corresponding lambda is `(x, y) -> x.compareTo(y)`. The stream `forEach` can only figure out one of `x` or `y`, so it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

The double colon or more accurately called "method reference"  is meant to a select a method that will be called.

And when calling methods, it matters greatly to match up the numbers of provided and expected arguments.

And as you can easily deduct, those counts do no match up for your second example.